# code for showing weekdays and nonweekdays in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Sub wd()
Dim Isweekday As Boolean
Select Case Weekday(A3, vbSaturday)
Case 1 To 2
Isweekday = False
Case Else
Isweekday = True
End Select
Range("A4").Value = Isweekday
End Sub
```

whats wrong in this code?...I want to show true for weekdays and false for  non weekdays

Answer (score 1):

Your code treats `A3` as an undeclared variable.

```
Select Case Weekday(Range("A3").Value, vbSaturday)
```

Shorter:

```
Sub wd()
    Range("A4").Value = (Weekday(Range("A3").Value, vbSaturday) > 2)
End Sub
```